# Slim route order declaration and route parameter

Tags: php, slim

I have many routes declared in my slim application.
Some of these have route parameters

```
$app->get("/:user/profile",function($user) use($app){ ... });
$app->get("/test/:id",function($id) use($app){ ... });
```

For example if I call:

```
http://myhost/test/1
```

It is suitable for both routes, then the declaration order is very important!
Is there any way to give priority to static router from parametrized?

Comment: is this your problem that two routes which may collide at the time of calling routes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tobia i hope want to this(for slim framework 2):

whenever if you have two routes in a file and you think that your two routes can be same URI at the time of calling So in that case use `pass()`

> A route can tell the Slim application to continue to the next matching
>   route with the Slim application's  pass() method

for your above case make some condition, try this like:

```
$app->get("/:user/profile",function($user) use($app){
    if($user == "POSSIBLE VALUES"){ // make condition that can be found in the $user parameter

    }
    else{
        $app->pass();
    }

});

$app->get("/test/:id",function($id) use($app){

});
```